# Right click popup menu in Processing

Tags: java, popup, processing

I am a beginner in both Java and Processing. I am trying to create a right click popup menu that will be displayed inside a processing jPanel. Part of the code I m using is displayed bellow, belongs to the class that extends PAplet. Initially, popup menu is displayed properly when right mouse buttonis pressed, but after using some other elements of the GUI, it doesnt appear on the screen anymore.

How to fix this? Shall I create the popup menu inside steup() method? Or elsewhere?

Thanks.

```
  private JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
  private JMenuItem edgeFrom = new JMenuItem("Edge From");
  private JMenuItem edgeTo = new JMenuItem("Edge To");

  @Override
  public void setup() {
    size(desiredheight,desiredwidth);
    background(255); 
    PopupActionHandler handler = new PopupActionHandler();
    edgeFrom.addActionListener(handler);
    edgeTo.addActionListener(handler);
    menu.add(edgeFrom);
    menu.add(edgeTo);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
            if (evt.isPopupTrigger()) {
                menu.show(evt.getComponent(), evt.getX(), evt.getY());
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: The popup will only display if the mouse event for the component can be triggered.  If you've added other components to the panel, they may be blocking the popup

Comment: I read sometimes that it may be tricky to combine Swing components with Processing, which is based on AWT.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below reference link for JPopupMenu

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AsimpleexampleofJPopupMenu.htm